# Navigation CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css

I have this navigation and its not showing up in the position I want it to.

http://jamessuske.com/thornwood2/

I would like to have it next to the logo on the right side, for some reason it shows up on the right at the very top. (kinda hard to describe, but im sure once u see it, u will know what I am talking about)

HTML CODE

```
<div class="header">

<div class="logo">
<img src="images/logo.jpg" width="350" height="120" border="0" />
</div><!--logo-->

<div class="nav">
Home | About Us | Gallery | Contact Us
</div><!--nav-->

</div><!--header-->
```

CSS CODE

```
.header{
width:1009px;
}

.logo{
float:left;
width:350px;
}

.nav{
float:right;
width:260px;
color:#FFF;
}
```

Also while I am here in IE 7 there is a gap between the topConent and the contentArea, also between the contentArea and bottomContent

http://jamessuske.com/thornwood2/

HTML CODE

```
<div class="topContent">
<img src="images/top.gif" width="1009" height="37" border="0" />
</div><!--topContent-->

<div class="leftContent">
<img src="images/leftSide.gif" width="48" height="494" border="0" />
</div><!--leftContent-->

<div class="contentArea">

</div><!--contentArea-->

<div class="rightContent">
<img src="images/rightSide.gif" width="49" height="494" border="0" />
</div><!--rightContent-->

<div class="bottomContent">
<img src="images/bottom.gif" width="1009" height="39" border="0" />
</div><!--bottomContent-->
```

Any help with either issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Oops forgot the CSS code for the IE7 bug

Comment: CSS CODE

    .topContent{
 width:1009px;
    }

    .leftContent{
 float:left;
    }

    .contentArea{
 background:#FFF;
 width:912px;
 min-height:494px;
 float:left;
    }

    .rightContent{
 float:right;
    }

    .bottomContent{
 width:1009px;
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav { float:left; }
```

if you want it next to the picture. If you want it on the right but further down - just crop your picture. It has some whitespace up the top, or add margin-top:20px or so.

IE7 bug
As of the bug you need to remove padding and margin from each picture and div so do something like this for each div.

```
.top-content
{
padding:0px;margin:0px;
}
.top-content img
{
padding:0px;margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: well I still want it on the right side, just down, so its at the same level as the logo

Comment: add margin to it .nav {margin-top:10px;}

Comment: Removing the padding and margin for the top and bottom images didn't work, there is still a gap in IE 7

Comment: you have to do all images in all divs .topContent, .leftContent. container - all of them.